# plotting a Histogram with a list of x and y values

Tags: histograms

I have a list of values :

```
m = Table[
  6.02*10^32*20*3.154*10^7*0.86*
   NIntegrate[\[Phi]n2[b]*f1[b]*10^-38, {b, i, i + 2}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 10], {i, 19, 29, 2}]
```

These are the y values. Now I have to plot these values with x from 19 to 31 and each value is for a interval of of 2 i.e from 19-21, 21-23 and so on. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

```
ledges = Range[19, 29, 2]
labels = StringTemplate["``-<*2+#*>"] /@ ledges
f1 = \[Phi]n2 = Function[x, x]  (* for illustration *)
m = Table[
  6.02*10^32*20*3.154*10^7*0.86*
   NIntegrate[\[Phi]n2[b]*f1[b]*10^-38, {b, i, i + 2}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 10], {i, ledges}]
BarChart[m, ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[7];
m = 10^6 RandomReal[10, 6]
```

> ```
> {8.29905*10^6, 7.00287*10^6, 6.20283*10^6, 6.48944*10^6,
>  9.15531*10^6, 7.19435*10^6}
> ```

```
binlist = Range[19, 31, 2];
```

You can use `m &` as the *height* specification in the third argument of `Histogram`:

```
Histogram[{1}, {binlist}, m &, Ticks -> {Range[19, 31, 2], Automatic}]
```

[image]

You can also use [`ListStepPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html) as follows:

```
ListStepPlot[m, Right, 
 DataRange -> {19, 29}, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 Ticks -> {Range[19, 31, 2], Automatic},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, All}}]
```

[image]